# what is the relation between SWD frequency and MCU frequency?

Tags: microcontroller, frequency, swd

I'm trying to connect to my board with SWD(serial wire debug) for frequency=4000khz with MCU which fixed frequency is 15KHz but it failed to connect.

Is there a specified relation or formula between this tow frequency to have max SWD frequency for MCU frequency 15KHz?

Comment: the swd frequency would have to be slower than the mcu main/system clock of course.  when you tried slowing down the swd frequency at what point did it start to work?

Comment: This relation should be documented in the data sheet of your MCU or an application note. Did you look into them?

Comment: it start working from 250KHz. i did look to them but i didn't find anything.do you have any idea about the relation or the formula to calculate the max SWD frequency for this MCU frequency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell: is there no formula. ST manual [UM0892](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/e6/10/d8/80/d6/1d/4a/f2/CD00262073.pdf/files/CD00262073.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00262073.pdf) tells us that the default frequency is `4000KHz` (aka `4MHz`) and can be set as low as `5KHz`.

My explanation for the lower options is the possibility to communicate with faulty/buggy hardware or hardware in a difficult situation where software/environmental conditions have made it so that communication at `4MHz` isn't reliable.

Lower frequencies have bigger amounts of time wherein the line is pulled to `'0'` or `'1'` which makes it harder for noise to mess with it. It also allows for more distance between the transition edges which might have spurious effects on the line because of possible factors (bad board design, PSU noise, etc etc)

Comment: but why when i use the under reset mode I can connect?

Comment: Seems like you haven't added all the information then. Do you use or disable the SWD pins at runtime?

Comment: i m using SWD pins at runtime

Comment: That is the reason why you need to keep the mcu under reset while you are starting your flashing. It keeps the mcu from configuring your SWD pins with alternate functions which might interfere with your SWD connection